# Looping through JSON array and print out same key values

Tags: arrays, powershell, epoch

Have JSON array with multiple keys of same which shows time in epoch, want to print then out and convert time to EST

```
{
"contents":[
      { 
        "name":"windows-Instance",
        "Buildid":"1234",
        "Buildtime":"1563350400238"
      },
      {
        "name":"linux-Instance",
        "Buildid":"1454",
        "Buildtime":"1563264000198"
      },
      {
      "name":"linux-Instance",
        "Buildid":"1278685",
        "Buildtime":"1563177600092"
       }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your PowerShell code so far, noting what isn't working as you expected and what is successful?  Please add that to your question via the [edit] button.

Comment: Here's a start.  `(get-content file.json | ConvertFrom-Json).contents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out to print each objects converted Epoch to current timezone:

```
Function Get-EpochDate ($epochDate) { [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddMilliseconds($epochDate)) }

$contents = (Get-Content .\test.json | ConvertFrom-Json).contents

foreach ($object in $contents) {
    $seconds = [long]$object.Buildtime
    Write-Output (Get-EpochDate $seconds)
}
```

Output:

```
Wednesday, 17 July 2019 4:00:00 PM
Tuesday, 16 July 2019 4:00:00 PM  
Monday, 15 July 2019 4:00:00 PM
```