# storing foreach loop output to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Have a JSON array with same key values , want to loop through those and get one key of the same value of the array and store the output to an array

```
{
"contents":[
      { 
        "name":"windows-Instance",
        "Buildid":"1234",
        "Buildtime":"1563350400238"
      },
      {
        "name":"linux-Instance",
        "Buildid":"1454",
        "Buildtime":"1563264000198"
      },
      {
      "name":"linux-Instance",
        "Buildid":"1278685",
        "Buildtime":"1563177600092"
       }
  ]
}
```

Here is code i tried and doesn't give any output.

```
 $result = @()


 foreach ($Builtime in $contents) {

 }

return $result
```

Comment: `$Buildtime` would be a variable for PowerShell to reference, not an enumerable amidst your dataset/JSON.  You're also not "doing anything" with `$result` - is that because you're not sure what to put there?

Comment: Why do you ask this while your _very similar_ question [Looping through JSON array and print out same key values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57083003/3439404) is answered already? However, both questions do not satisfy the [mcve] rules…

Comment: Why would $result be any different?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

First convert the json string to an object:

```
$contents = '{
    "contents":[
        { 
            "name":"windows-Instance",
            "Buildid":"1234",
            "Buildtime":"1563350400238"
        },
        {
            "name":"linux-Instance",
            "Buildid":"1454",
            "Buildtime":"1563264000198"
        },
        {
            "name":"linux-Instance",
            "Buildid":"1278685",
            "Buildtime":"1563177600092"
        }
    ]
}' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Than retrieve the required properties:

```
$result = $contents | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "contents" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Buildtime"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the JSON and create a custom-object that would allow you to further "manipulate" the data if needed.
Otherwise the example of @mhu is a perfect onliner

```
$json_content = (Get-Content ".\sample.json") | ConvertFrom-Json

$result = foreach ($content in $json_content."contents") {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Buildtime" = $content."Buildtime"
    }
}
```